# ImportError ugettext_lazy as _

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication

I am using Django 4 for my webApp and I started getting this error when I want to setup Authentication. I checked all the forum and I found that they suggest to import gettext_lazy as _. But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
This is the error I get when trying to run the dev server:

```
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation' (/Users/intelligentica/PycharmProjects/DockerDjangoReactProject/backend/mainapp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py)
```

I started getting the errors just after trying to setup user authentication:

```
from django.urls import path
from users.views import APILoginView, APILogoutView
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as authtoken_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', APILoginView.as_view(), name='api_login'),
    path('logout', APILogoutView.as_view(), name='api_logout'),
    path('generate-api-token', authtoken_views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

Comment: What error in what code? If you don't share, we cannot help.

Comment: Also, what in particular "doesn't work"?

Comment: I have edited the question to add the error I get.

Comment: Django 2.2 was the last version with `ugettext_lazy` :)

Answer (score 0):

The package you installed doesn't support Django 4 and includes `ugettext_lazy` which Django 4 doesn't support.

Try to reinstall this package
`pip uninstall  djangorestframework`
`pip install  djangorestframework`

or you can try to change all `ugettext_lazy` to `gettext_lazy` in this package folder.

e.g.
Django 2.2:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Django 2.2>:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: If you mean django.utils.translation, I didn't use it, that's the problem. Unless it is related to rest_framework.

Comment: As I said you installed a package that uses it.  I updated my answer please check